# Peak detector (peak event)

Tags: adc, signal

I have a problem which is somehow related to detecting a peak. Let me summarize the problem a little bit, so it might be clear to you. I have to signals, both are not periodic and I know when they start and when they end. I also know the signal has exactely one peak. The signal might be a bit noisy, but I think this could be eliminated.
Now I need to know when between the start and end point the peak occurs. The best option would be that I get an output signal as soon as the peak occurs. Yet, I do not know how high the peak will be. This can vary a lot. The signal itself looks like a gaussian.

Now I could use a high speed ADC and sample the signal continously, do some small calculations and get the peak. Yet, what I would like much more, would be if I simply get an "event" telling me: There was the peak. I don't mind if I get this signal a bit later, as long as the time difference between the peak and the event is constant. I absolutely do NOT care about the peak level, I only want to know the point in time when this happened.

Does anyone know of a circuit which is able to satisfy these requirements?

Comment: Tom, how wide is your peak?  What's the maximum wait time?  What are the desired time resolution and accuracy?  Give us an idea of scale.

Comment: @NickAlexeev: Yes, that's a very good question and I do not have the answers yet (I will get sample signals on Thursday). Basically each cycle will last 1ms longest. Within this 1ms everything will take place. I expect the peak to be around 100us long (90%) and I expect it to be a bit noisy. Time resolution and accuracy are not very critical, I'd say 10-15% are still acceptable (although less is better) as there will be a large number of measurements to build an average (around 500-100 measurements)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't especially like the idea of doing this with a differentiator, because your gaussian pulse has a relatively flat top, so there will be a time when the derivative is *nearly* zero, so that the moment when you detect the peak will be fairly noise sensitive.

If the shape and amplitude of the input pulse is the same each time, you may be able to get what you want with a standard op-amp peak-detector followed by a comparator:

[image]

What this is doing is not trying to detect the peak event directly, but detecting when the input (IN) falls by one diode drop below the peak. When this happens, you'll get a rising edge at OUT.

After each cycle, your micro should assert the CLR line to clear out the peak detector.

You could reduce the delay from the peak to the output edge by using a schottky diode at D2. If your pulse is very slow, the value of C1 and R1 also need to be chosen large enough so that the capacitor doesn't bleed down too quickly after the peak.

The diode and FET types are just the default ones in CircuitLab. You'll want to choose these more carefully.

You'll want to choose an op-amp appropriate for the time scale of your signal, and you'll also need one that is okay being used as a comparator (e.g. one that doesn't go crazy when its two inputs are not at the same voltage and that can recover reasonably quickly from being driven to the rails).

**Edit:** I updated the schematic, adding R2 in the FET drain, to avoid extreme currents through D1 in the event the pulse arrives while you are resetting. Ideally you'll give your reset pulse at a time when you know the pulse won't occur. Otherwise, you'll need to make R2 big enough that you don't blow out OA2 or D1 if it does arrive when CLR is asserted; and make the CLR pulse width long enough to fully discharge C1 through R2.

Comment: Thank you for the idea (and the schematics). I will try to simulate those in LTSpice or TINA with my custom Signal as soon as I get the data. What I think about is making the circuit with a single supply as I will never have a negative sweep. I think I'll have to check for matching OPamps. One Thing I'm not quite sure about is OA4. Is this the comparator part and D2 is the Diode which defines the Signal drop that has to occur to really detect a Peak?

Comment: Yes, OA4 is the comparator, and D2 defines how far below the peak does the input have to go before the output is asserted.

Comment: If your input pulse is regular enough and the duty cycle is low enough, you could probably get rid of M1 and R2, and adjust R1 so that the reset happens "by itself" without needing intervention from the control logic.

Comment: This solution is no more noise immune than the differentiator. In fact, there are two ways in which noise affects this design: positive noise peaks will drive the peak-hold part of the circuit too high, and negative noise peaks will trigger the comparator too soon. Either way, the output will occur early with respect to the noise-free case.

Comment: @DaveTweed, Obviously the circuit isn't totally noise-immune. But because the trigger event happens on a steeper part of the input pulse, noise of, say, 1 uV will cause less error in the timing of the output pulse.

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure there is only a single peak, then you can differentiate the signal and compare to zero.  I'm a bit rushed right now, but a simple way to make a differentiator is a opamp in inverting configuration with a capacitor on its input.

One problem with a differentiator is that it is susceptible to noise.  Put another way, it will show you all the little local maximums in the signal resulting from noise if there are any.  Low pass filtering the signal to eliminate frequencies you know don't matter would be a good idea.

Comment: Also, using a small offset at the comparator will reject differentiated noise up to a certain amplitude, with the drawback that it will delay the recognition of the peak by a certain amount of time.

Comment: Thank you for the hint with differentiating the Signal. I would personally like this solution very much for its simplicity but I fear that the Signal might be very noisy. I should get a sample at the end of this week and might then be able to say something more about the Quality of the Signal. Low pass filtering is always a good idea but still I fear that Signal will not be that easy to handle.

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTEdVt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Peak hold detector: Working fine with 1us peaking time (width = 5 us) semi-gaussian analog signal  from my CZT detector + front-end electronics.